# Loop through a array, find the selected option value of each divs contained into this array and assign a background color

Tags: jquery, html

In a div container, I have many other divs (which are orders) which contains 5 other divs, and the third of this div contain a select from which I need to check the selected value in order to set the background-color of the `div class="order"` depending the selected value.

```
<div class="container-fluid form-inline" id="data">

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                        </div>

</div>
```

Each `div class="order"` looks the same :

```
                        <div class="order" row-id="X" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                             
                        </div>
```

This is the select into the third row :

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 status">
        <h5>Statut</h5>
        <p>
            <select disabled="" class=" form-control">
                    <option value="">Status</option>
                            <option value="1">A valider</option>
                            <option value="2">Non traitée</option>
                            <option value="3" selected="">En traitement</option>
                            <option value="4">Achevée</option>
                            <option value="5">Annulée</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

So the data to loop through look as followed :

```
<div class="container-fluid form-inline" id="data">

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 status">
                                    <h5>Statut</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        <select disabled="" class=" form-control">
                                                <option value="">Status</option>
                                                        <option value="1" selected="">A valider</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Non traitée</option>
                                                        <option value="3">En traitement</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Achevée</option>
                                                        <option value="5">Annulée</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                             
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 status">
                                    <h5>Statut</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        <select disabled="" class=" form-control">
                                                <option value="">Status</option>
                                                        <option value="1">A valider</option>
                                                        <option value="2" selected="">Non traitée</option>
                                                        <option value="3">En traitement</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Achevée</option>
                                                        <option value="5">Annulée</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                             
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 status">
                                    <h5>Statut</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        <select disabled="" class=" form-control">
                                                <option value="">Status</option>
                                                        <option value="1">A valider</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Non traitée</option>
                                                        <option value="3" selected="">En traitement</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Achevée</option>
                                                        <option value="5">Annulée</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                             
                        </div>

                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 status">
                                    <h5>Statut</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        <select disabled="" class=" form-control">
                                                <option value="">Status</option>
                                                        <option value="1">A valider</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Non traitée</option>
                                                        <option value="3">En traitement</option>
                                                        <option value="4" selected="">Achevée</option>
                                                        <option value="5">Annulée</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row"></div>                 
                            <div class="row"></div>                             
                        </div>

</div>
```

I need now to find the selected value of each select and depending on the selected value to assign a different background-color to its `div class="order"`

```
                        <div class="order" row-id="1242" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; position: ">
                        </div>
```

I managed to do it for a for a table with tr and td and it was working fine with this jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").each(function(){
        var col_val = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").text();
        if (col_val == "A valider"){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffe5e5');
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(13) > div > a.btn.btn-xs.btn-success.btn-edit").hide();
        } else if (col_val == "Non traitée"){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f6dcab');
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(13) > div > a.btn.btn-xs.btn-success.btn-edit").hide();
        // $(this).addClass('selected'); // the selected class color
        } else if (col_val == "En traitement"){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#d2d2f2');
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(13) > div > a.btn.btn-xs.btn-success.btn-edit").hide();
        // $(this).addClass('selected'); // the selected class color
        } else if (col_val == "Achevée"){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#c4ffc4');
        // $(this).addClass('selected'); // the selected class color
        }
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to start with this div structured form.

I guess I have to start with the following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#data").each(function(){
        var col_val = $(this).find("div > div:nth-child(4) > div.col-md-6.status > p > select > option:nth-child(4)").text();
```

but after it is a mystery. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("#data .order").each(function (index, value) {
    var selectedValue = $(this).find(".status select").children("option:selected")[0].text; 
    console.log(selectedValue);

    if( selectedValue == "A valider" )  {
       $(this).css('background-color', "yellow");
    }      
    else if(selectedValue == "Annulée") {
     $(this).css('background-color', "blue");
    }     
 });

 // A valider
 // Non traitée
 // En traitement
 // Achevée
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do:

```
// Get the selected option from all the selects
$('#data select option:selected').each( function() {
   let selectedText = $(this).text();
   let cssColor     = 'white';

   // Set the desired related text color
   if(selectedText === 'A valider') {
       cssColor = 'blue';
   }
   else if ( selectedText === 'Non traitée' ) {
       cssColor = 'red';
   }
   // Cover other texts and colors as needed

   // Apply the color to the related div with the order class
   $(this).closest('div .order').css('background-color', cssColor)
});
```

That sample run looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and your function which is working, well. I have tested it and as you say, text inherit the appropriate color. Sadly, I can not accept your answer since I have asked :

I need now to find the selected value of each select and depending on the selected value to assign a different background-color to its div class="order"

Sorry. Anyway, I have learned something new today. Thank you for that.

Comment: Ok, it is a minor edit anyway. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order").each(function(){

var selectedVal = $(this).find("select option:selected").html();

switch(selectedVal){
case "A valider":
  $(this).css({"background-color":"red"})
  break;

case "En traitement":
  $(this).css({"background-color":"green"})
  break;

}

})

})
```

Comment: Thank you ! Murali Nepalli solved already my issue, cheers, Marc